# SwiftUI Finding Solution for Button overlay on Image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I overlayed a button/text on the image, but the button didnt respond. Is there any solution?
It seems like the hidden navigation bar view is blocking the button or the image is blocking the touch gesture. How should I fix this?

```
struct Tutorial: View {
    let dataModel = DataModel()
    @State var messageIndex = 0

    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            
            Image("Tutorial UI")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
                .overlay(
                    VStack(spacing:20){
                        VStack(spacing:30){
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Next")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .fontWeight(.black)
                                .onTapGesture(count:1) {
                                    
                                    if self.messageIndex != 4{
                                        self.messageIndex += 1
                                    }else{
                                        self.messageIndex = 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Text(dataModel.tutorialMessage[messageIndex][0])
                                .fontWeight(.black)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }.padding()
                        Text(dataModel.tutorialMessage[messageIndex][1])
                            .font(.title)
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 48)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                        
                    
                    
                    
            )
            
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0,  maxHeight: .infinity, 
    alignment: .center)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The debug view hierarchy with button on the top(covered)]
[image: The debug view hierarchy with button on the top(covered)]
[image: The debug view hierarchy with button below the title text(half-covered)]
[image: The debug view hierarchy with button below the title text(half-covered]

Comment: It is hard to reproduce your case due to many absent dependencies in provided code snapshot. Do you see the button (ie. text with tap gesture) on screen? Did you try breakpoint inside tap action to see if it goes there? Minimal reproducible example would be much more useful.

Comment: Another thing you will find is you can’t really ask follow on questions in a post. The answer is yes, as a NavigationBarButton, and Google will give you MANY examples and tutorials on how to use them. I will say, that you can’t hide the NavigationBar and use a NavigationBarButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Asperi was getting at is you have provided a code snippet that depends upon a model we know nothing about. When you post code, you should post a simplified version. In this case I took your code and swapped out your data model for a simple array. I also downloaded an image to use from NASA's Image of the Day to use. And, Asperi nailed the problem with his second question...

Looking at it, the first thing that struck me is you are trying too hard to position things just so in SwiftUI. It doesn't work that way. And that led to your problems. I pulled out your frames which actually don't do anything in this layout. I also pulled out the specific padding amounts. I then pulled the Spacer() out that was in your HStack, and your "Next" button appeared on the screen. I suspect that setting the image as .scaledToFill() and an image that is not in the same dimensions of the screen caused the view to be larger than the screen you could see. Putting the Spacer() in caused your "Next" button to move all of the way to the right, which was off screen. Once I could see it, I was able to click it and it worked fine.

You have an extremely complicated structure that produces a pretty simple layout. Next time, start small and only add what you need. Less layout is better in SwiftUI, or you end up with unintended consequences. Try changing the HStack in your Overlay to the following and then work from there, one step at a time:

```
                        HStack{
                            Text("Next")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .fontWeight(.black)
                                .onTapGesture(count:1) {
                                    
                                    if self.messageIndex != 4{
                                        self.messageIndex += 1
                                    }else{
                                        self.messageIndex = 0
                                    }
                                }
                        }
```

Remember, in SwiftUI the Child View determines its own size. Don't try to force things from a Parent.